# Does every group grow either polynomially or superpolynomially?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I am reading [an introduction to growth of groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607384). The notions of polynomial and superpolynomial growth are introduced, as are exponential and subexponential growth.

I can prove that the growth of a group is always either exponential or subexponential (it is exercise 1.6). However, there seems to be no mention of an analogous result for (super)polynomial growth (i.e. the growth of a group is always either polynomial or superpolynomial).

There exist strictly increasing functions which grow faster than polynomially but are not superpolynomial (this is pretty clear; a more detailed explanation can be found in the second section of [this document](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0599v1)), but I do not know whether these occur as the growth function of some group.

[The thesis of a Nick Scott](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/publications/ScottNick.pdf) claims to prove that every group grows either polynomially or superpolynomially, but I don't see it (it is in subsection 1.4.1, on p.12; it seems to me the proof assumes that the limit $\log(\beta(k))/\log(k)$ exists, but I don't know why).

So my question is: **does every group grow either polynomially or superpolynomially?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. This is a result of Grigorchuk, see his Mittag-Leffler notes.[link text](http://www.mittag-leffler.se/preprints/files/IML-1112s-06.pdf) (Milnor's problem on the growth of groups and its consequences, available on line for free; see page 28).

Comment: seems to be p. 19, Cor. 8.6

Comment: @Agol, yes, true, but the same result is mentioned in a broader "Gap" context on pp 28-29.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is indeed mentioned in cor. 8.6 and on page 28-29. On page 18 there is mention of work by van der Dries and Wilkie also proving it.

Comment: The link in the message is broken. Here's the arxiv link: http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0512

Comment: By the way Grigorchuk in this survey does not claim this result as his own result. As far as I remember, I think it's folklore that it follows from Gromov's original proof.

Answer (score 6):

It is interesting that another asymptotic invariant of a group, the Dehn function, can be arbitrary large (even non-recursive) but still bounded by a polynomial on an infinite set. In fact the polynomial can be made quadratic. See [this paper.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1476)